# unable to understand the output of union program in C

Tags: c, unions

I know the basic properties of `union` in C but still couldn't understand the output, can somebody explain this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        union uni_t{
                int i;
                char ch[2];
        };
        union uni_t z ={512};
        printf("%d%d",z.ch[0],z.ch[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

The output when running this program is

```
02
```

Comment: those union members have different size. warning flag.

Comment: 512 = 0x20
On little-endian, you'd get {0,2}, I'd think, so it seems right

Comment: @dwn You mean 512 = 0x200.

Comment: Er, yeah, I blame this foggy early morning

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Using unions for type-punning is legal according to footnote 82 in TC3 of the C99 standard (though it is implementation-defined, of course, and some implementations could have padding or trap values that would result in UB)

Comment: @UmNyobe Only if `sizeof(int) != 2`.

Comment: @Which is quite common, isn't it?

Comment: @user694733: which would be the case for almost any non-16bit architecture? Which, by the way, I'd blindly assume is used, since the original post uses stdio.h, ie. is not running on some minimalistic microcontroller?

Comment: @PascalCuoq char doesn't have trap representation so it is defined.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I wouldn't be too hasty to assume non-16bit architecture. OP may have copied code from book, and using stdio.h functions even in embedded system is possible, especially when semihosting.

Comment: @user694733:I'd agree,but in this day and age,if you're asking about unions,you're not in charge of managing legacy code.An embedded platform that you'd want to use stdio.h is most probably 32bit.There's a few instances where you'd e.g. be using the uC that came with your USB controller,but then again,even those are either really low-end 8bit controllers,or something 32bitty.Memory prices & the availability of ARM cores make it hard to justify using something in between 8 and 32bit(where you can use the machine word width for almost any counter,without always having to carry around 2xint16_t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
union a
{
    int i;
    char ch[2];
}
```

This declares a type `union a`, the contents of which (i.e. the memory area of a variable of this type) could be accessed as **either** an integer (`a.i`) **or** a 2-element char array (`a.ch`).

```
union a z ={512};
```

This defines a variable `z` of type `union a` and initializes its first member (which happens to be `a.i` of type `int`) to the value of `512`. (Cantfindname has the binary representation of that.)

```
printf( "%d%d", z.ch[0], z.ch[1] );
```

This takes the first character, then the second character from `a.ch`, and prints their numerical value. Again, Cantfindname talks about endianess and how it affects the results. Basically, you are taking apart an `int` byte-by-byte.

And the whole shebang is apparently *assuming* that `sizeof( int ) == 2`, which hasn't been true for desktop computers for... quite some time, so you might want to be looking at a more up-to-date tutorial. ;-)

Comment: please precise that `union a z ={512};`  initializes `int i` because it is the first member of the union.

Comment: @DevSolar: i386 was 1985/86, so this year it's going to be 30 years :) maybe you want to add that to your answer, just for the historical touch ;)

Comment: @MarcusMüller: The point is that I **never** worked on a 386. The computing world is much larger than that. At least, it *was* back in those days. Personally, I went from Z80 to MOS 8502 to MC68000 to MC68030 to PPC603e (yes, those were the Amiga days...) to Pentium III... ;-)

Comment: :D yep, I think these days of diversity have passed. Cost and complexity considerations either force you to stay 8bit (which is totally ok, if you're just switching on an LED after switch A and B have been closed, and C has been opened more than 2s ago), or you're just having yourself an 32 bit microcontroller; I'm really not in favor of having to use something that doesn't fit my CPU's registers if I just want to count bytes in my packet,do an IPv4 address calculation,tune my RF frontend to 934.32744MHz,keep track of RGB pixels on a 150x150 display or buffer more than 2/3s of 44.1kHz audio.

Answer (score 1):

What you get here is the result of endianess (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

512 is 0b0000 0010 0000 0000 in binary, which in little endian is stored in the memory as 0000 0000 0000 0010. Then ch[0] reads the last 8 bits (0b0000 0010 = 2 in decimal) and ch[1] reads the first 8 bits (0b0000 0000 = 0 in decimal).

Comment: what's the significance of "0b"

Comment: @JerryGoyal: prefix for "binary number"

Answer (score 0):

*Using int will not lead to this output in 32 bit machines as sizeof(int) = 4. This output will occur only if we use a 16 bit system or we use **short int** having memory size of 2 bytes.*

A Union is a variable that may hold (at different times) objects of different types and sizes, with the compiler keeping track of size and alignment requirements.

```
union uni_t
{
      short int i;
      char ch[2];
};
```

This code snippet declares a union having two members- a integer and a character array.
The union can be used to hold different values at different times by simply allocating the values.

```
union uni_t z ={512};
```

This defines a variable z of type union uni_t and initializes the integer member ( i ) to the value of 512.

So the value stored in z becomes : 0b0000 0010 0000 0000

When this value is referenced using character array then ch[1] refers to first byte of data and ch[0] refers to second byte.

ch[1] = 0b00000010 = 2
ch[0] = ob00000000 = 0

So `printf("%d%d",z.ch[0],z.ch[1])` results to

> 02